# Storage Spaces - drives with different capacity

Tags: storage-spaces

I'm looking at Storage Spaces as a software based RAID replacement solution. I am planning on moving my disks to a new computer in the near future, yet I want to move data in now.

Also, I have not finished buying drives. Right now I have 4x1TB and 1x2TB drives.

**Is Storage Spaces smarter than RAID-5 or RAID-0 and won't waste 1TB off the 2TB drive?**

I have already read a lot on it, and searched for this information, yet nothing comes up to infirm or confirm it. I can't test, as I haven't moved all data off the disks yet, which requires further investment.

Comment: "Smarter than Raid 0 and wonÄt WASTE"? Sorry but can you pelase at least get a basic understanding what Riad 5 DOES and WHY it looses space before claiming it is waste.

Comment: I'm trying to understand Storage Spaces and planning on using it. I know there will be wasted space on parity, and I know how RAID-5 works. To make it clearer, the question was wether Storage Spaces can use a single double size disk as a single parity disk when crossing the 7 disk boundary, which would advantage me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have the full grasp of what JBOD and RAID is.

JBOD is a bunch of disks. Nothing else. No resillency, no protection, nothing. Just disks. Is this what you want?

Or do you want to build a RAID on top of the disks (the JBOD), without using a raid controller? If so, then yes - Storage Spaces is one of your choices.

Storage Spaces does not "waste" capacity. You, the admin, select how much resillience against disk failure(s) you need.